# AT what level of position a person may be AT

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Let's say your giving an opinion about each gender's(male and female) leisure time, on how they spend their free time at weekends. And your opinion is:

> "It depends on the type of job, or **at** what level of position a person may be **at**.

Or

> "It depends on the type of job, or **at** what level of position a person may be **in**.

Which is the correct preposition?

Comment: **depends** governs your choices here.  *Depends **on** the type of job or **on** the role ...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither makes sense.  You only need one *at* in the first example and you only need one of *at* and *in* in the second.  So a better sentence might be:

> It depends on the type of job, or what level a person is at.

There is another irregularity in both sentences.  It doesn't make sense to talk about the *level of position* someone is at.  You either talk about *the level they're at* or *the position they're in*.  Here's how I'd phrase it as a native speaker:

> It depends on the job and their title.

One's title (in the context of employment) refers to one's role in the organisation, e.g. CEO, salesperson, janitor.

Answer (score 1):

You can be ***at*** a certain level, or ***in*** a certain position, so I think either preposition would work in this particular case.

Still, I think the sentence would be improved if you eliminated the prepositions altogether:

> *It depends on the type of job, or the person's position level*.